# Evaluate number of pixel given font-size and font-family in java

Tags: java, font-size, fontmetrics

I have a custom string. I can have dynamic length, font-size and font-family. Once I know how much number of pixels this text is going to occupy I would be able to truncate it if it does not fit inside its parent.

Here, I cannot draw string or box while I am evaluating the pixels but I have all the information like font size and font family. I am using java.

Comment: did any of the answers help you? if that is the case feel free to accept one.

Answer (score 1):

if you need the lenght of your `String` based on the `label`, you can work with:

```
lYourLabel.getFontMetrics(lYourLabel.getFont()).stringWidth("Hello World");
```

I am using that method to cut the displayed String and expand it with "..." inside a resizable `TableColumn`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a couple methods I use for this sort of thing:

```
public static int getTextWidth(Font font, String text) {
    FontMetrics metrics = new FontMetrics(font) {};
    Rectangle2D bounds = metrics.getStringBounds(text, null);
    return (int) bounds.getWidth();
}

public static int getTextHeight(Font font, String text) {
    FontMetrics metrics = new FontMetrics(font) {};
    Rectangle2D bounds = metrics.getStringBounds(text, null);
    return (int) bounds.getHeight();
}
```